# Android Studio 0.2.6 update broke my project, asks me to setup jdk

Tags: android, android-studio

I updated Android Studio to 0.2.6 today and there is red everywhere in my project now. When I click to see the automatic fix it asks me to setup jdk.

[image]

After selecting `Setup JDK` the following screen appears:

[image]

Whatever I choose, nothing happens. Everything stays red, and if I click again it still says setup jdk.

Comment: I just go back to 0.2.5, as the new 0.2.6 comes with a new gradle which does not seem to know android sdk. I got a proceed screen with a proceed button which says there is a lot changes are not compatible when I upgrade from 0.2.5 to 0.2.6. Did you see that also?

Comment: I don't remember seeing that screen.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A simple restart of Android Studio solved the problem.

Comment: True, but that should always be a first step if your previously working project turns red.  Don't spend an hour at the start of your day trying to out-think an issue like this, unless you like SO! So plus one for helping the uninitiated!  Thought I might be able to swoop in with a fix for this one...early dev gets the ups.

Comment: Yeah I felt like an idiot when I realized I hadn't restarted yet. I think the reason I didn't initially consider it is because Android Studio restarts itself after installing the update.

Comment: If I didn't already spend hours on R.java restarts in Eclipse and the like, I wouldn't think to restart right away either.  Thinking "A gremlin came in over night and messed up my xml" is not a viable theory, but it's a great way to dig deeper into the inner-workings of previously unknown project settings and IDE features, like what @Owen mentioned, so remove "idiot" from your vocabulary soldier!

Comment: Restarting after the IDE restarted itself didn't seem so obvious to me. But it should have, it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 12):

File -> Invalidate caches/restart worked for me.

Comment: worked for me as well.
what's funny project was building just fine, the problem was only with editor and lot's of reds near prefectly fine java/android code.

Comment: Yes! Thanks a bunch. Happened after a BSOD. I did everything. Deleted all files, created a new project and moved files. Reinstalled. Downloaded a canary version. Downgraded to beta. Downloaded JAVA 8 and JAVA 7. Everything. This solved my issue.

Funny, the project was building fine as well @pelotasplus

Comment: Apparently this can happen under 2 circumstances, if you had an update a restart should do, if your computer crashed (like mine) then this works. Sigh, just another thing not to like about this...

Answer (score 0):

Close and restart Android Studio that will fixes it.